# Angularjs - filter results from rest api based on value of textbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

OK - so I have the following service:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource'])
     .factory('STLineup', function($resource){
        return $resource('http://someapi.com?filters=location.eventInstance.slug:Slug,artists.tags:ArtistTags,location.name:LocationName', 
            {Slug: '@Slug', ArtistTags: '@ArtistTags', LocationName: '@LocationName'})
      });
```

And the following controller:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'STLineup', function($scope, stl) {

    $scope.items = {};

    stl.get({'Slug': ':xxxxx-2014', 'ArtistTags': ':electronic|grime', 'LocationName': ':Snakepit'},function(response) {
        $scope.items = response.results;
    });

    $scope.changeCallback = function() {
        stl.get({'Slug': ':xxxxxx-2014', 'ArtistTags': ':electronic|grime'},function(response) {
        $scope.items = response.results;
    });
   }
}]);
```

And the following directive:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
    .directive('appLineup', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AEC',
            scope: {
              items: '=',
                  change: '&changeCallback'
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

            },
            templateUrl: 'templates/lineup.html'
      };
    }]);
```

And the following template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="LocationName" ng-change="change()" />
<br/>
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <p class="title">{{item.name}}</p> 
</div>
```

Which is added to the UI using the following:

```
<app-lineup items="items" change-callback="change()" />
```

PHEW!!

So - the initial data is being loaded in but the `change` event is never getting fired into? What am I doing wrong here?!

Here is the code in app.js;

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngResource',
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
  $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

Comment: You don't show how/if the controller is used.

Comment: This is straight from the seed app - added the code from app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `change()` function is declared in you controller's scope, but since your directive uses an isolate scope (i.e. one that doesn't prototypally inherit from its parent), it knows nothing about it.
You could pass it to the directive's scope like this:

```
<!-- The VIEW -->
<app-lineup items="items" change-callback="change()" />

/* The DIRECTIVE */
...
scope: {
    ...
    change: '&changeCallback'
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work - I've edited the answer with my updated code

Comment: my mistake - I've missed some bits

Comment: The function on the controller should **not** be renamed. It should remain `$scope.change`. Please, only update the parts that I mention in my answer.

Comment: Sorry to push you after marking this as the answer, but how do I get the value of the txtbox into the filter for the GET request?

Comment: You can't unless you declare it in the parent-scope and create a two-way binding by means of and appropriate attribute and `scope:{...locationName: '='}`

Answer (score 0):

```
scope.change = function() {
```

Forgetting your $, which in turn is not allowing change() in your template to do anything.

```
scope.items = response.results;
```

Forgetting your $.

Comment: Sorry - I was moving some stuff about in the SO editor :/ I already tried that and no luck

Comment: Updated the q to reflect this